# Does webview work on Windows Phone 8 and 8.1?

Tags: windows-phone-8, webview, windows-phone-8.1, windows-phone, cocos2d-x

Cocos2d-x 3.3 and above have "web view". While web view 3.3 is not compatible with windows phone, I am wondering if any of the later versions of cocos2d-x are compatible with windows phone ? The documentation does not mention this.

EDIT: It seems that in cocos2d-x v3.7, web view does not work in Windows Phone (the project won't compile because there isn't an implementation for windows).

Is there an alternative that one can easily integrate with cocos2d-x do display web pages ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Till cocos2d-x 3.10 Webview is only for android and IOS devices. Its not even for Mac or windows pc, windows phone etc.

Comment: what about for 3.11+ ?

Comment: I hevnt tried, but its not mention anywhere in cocos2d website, so I don't think they have implemented it there...